# SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass:GetVoices does crash my Unity executable

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech

I created a project with Unity (version 4.5.3f3).
I only wrote a simple script as follow:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SpeechLib;

public class SpeechTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpVoice voice;

    void Start()
    {
        voice = new SpVoice();
        voice.GetVoices("","");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            voice.Speak("Hello, world!", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can download the test project for Unity: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12184013/TextToSpeech.zip

When I try to play (in Unity editor), the game runs without problems. 
Instead, when I build and run the game, it crashes.

When i comment this line

```
ISpeechObjectTokens voices = voice.GetVoices();
```

the game doesn't crash after I rebuilt it.

I need to call GetVoices method, because I want to set a new voice in the "SpVoice voice" object.

Comment: How can I add SpeechLib reference to my csproj project ? Which is the name in COM tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/speechlib-spvoiceclass-getvoices-does-crash-my-unity-executable.268011/#post-1772720

In a nutshell the library [Unity Install Directory]\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\CustomMarshalers.dll should be included in the Unity project (adding it as a asset).